# How to solve type error in django? TypeError at /new/ HttpResponse() takes no arguments

Tags: django-views, django-urls

'''django views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def fun1(request):
q = "

## welcome to Django website

"
return HttpResponse(q)

def fun2(request):
return render(request, 'index.html')''

Comment: Share teh related view, as well as the *full* traceback.

Comment: views.py                                                                                                                       
 from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def fun2(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

Comment: Please, share the full traceback as *code* (not an *image*). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.